# Problem with exporting a proxy object (to collada .dae) including texture, material and animation

Tags: animation, texturing, linked-data, collada, append

i spent a lot of time on this topic and cannot find any solution.

I **linked** my already rigged and textured character (as proxy) to a new blender file and created the animation for the **proxy armature**.
Here my current setup in the outliner

[image]

Now i want to export this scene to a collada file. (The "Include Material Textures" Checkbox is enabled.) but:

1. No textures / materials will be copied to the destination.
2. The animation doesn't work, because it seems like the "Body" object is not connected to the proxy armature.

**Side note: The animation works fine in blender. It breaks only after exporting. I tried to include the "Body" object also as proxy but then i have to reassign the mesh to the armature and my weight-painting breaks.**

So my questions are:

1. How can i export my **proxy object** to a collada file including textures / materials?
2. How can i export my **proxy object** to a collada file including a working animation?

Hopefully anybody has a solution for that... :(

Thanks and regards

Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it by myself. The texture problem can be solved, by copying all necessary files (*Specular.png, *Opacity.png, *Diffuse.png ...) by hand to the same destination like the *.dae will be stored and **disable the "Copy"**  and **enable "Include Material Textures"** checkbox in the collada export settings.

The animation only works, if i set the body object to local (so its assignable to the proxy armature). The mesh, materials and textures are still linked, so i'm still able to change them in my origin blend file.